# Django Ajax CSRF error 403 or 500

Tags: ajax, django, csrf, django-csrf

I try to change the admin interface. I have added a field to change the status of the Order in my shop application via Ajax.

I base on this Django snippet *[Admin list_display Ajax](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/568/)*.

This is my JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.order-helper').css("margin", "0");
    $('.order-helper').blur(function(){
        var input = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: "/ajax-status-update/"+ input.attr('name') +"/",
            data: order=input.attr('value'),
            type: "POST",
            complete: function(xhr_obj, msg){
                if (msg == 'success') {
                    input.css("border", "1px solid green");
                } else {
                    input.css("border", "1px solid red");
                }
            },
        });

    });
});
```

This is my view:

```
def order_helper(request, prod_id):
prod = get_object_or_404(FixedOrder, id=prod_id)
prod.status = request.POST.get('order')
prod.save()
return HttpResponse(content='Ok', status=200)
```

The view works with not Ajax call.

I read tons of articles about this and nothing works for me. I know that it is connected somehow with [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery). In the console I get a 403 error.

I read that I have to add this JavaScript snippet anywhere:

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function(event, xhr, settings) {
    function getCookie(name) {
        var cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
            var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }
    function sameOrigin(url) {
        // url could be relative or scheme relative or absolute
        var host = document.location.host; // host + port
        var protocol = document.location.protocol;
        var sr_origin = '//' + host;
        var origin = protocol + sr_origin;
        // Allow absolute or scheme relative URLs to same origin
        return (url == origin || url.slice(0, origin.length + 1) == origin + '/') ||
            (url == sr_origin || url.slice(0, sr_origin.length + 1) == sr_origin + '/') ||
            // or any other URL that isn't scheme relative or absolute i.e relative.
            !(/^(\/\/|http:|https:).*/.test(url));
    }
    function safeMethod(method) {
        return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
    }

    if (!safeMethod(settings.type) && sameOrigin(settings.url)) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie('csrftoken'));
    }
});
```

But if I add this I get 500 in the console. How can I check what kind of problem it is?
Maybe I miss a CSRF token?

Comment: If you have Firebug, there will be a "HTML" tab in the console when you make your AJAX request, and then you can see what your error is.

Comment: In html tab I see only html document, can u explain what to do?

Comment: If you got a 500 error, the HTML page should say what the error was. I was just wondering what the error was.

Comment: This is an ajax call so I don't see anything. Only in development server i see post request ended with 500.

Comment: Yeah but you can see the POST request in the Firebug console, and if you have your Django DEBUG set to True, the HTML page will give you details of the error.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Error: "Key 'order' not found in <QueryDict: {u'A': [u'']}>" Where "A" is a value which I put to ajax form. Any ideas?:>

Comment: I've changed: data: {order: input.attr('value')}, in js script and now it works! Thanks a lot WAITINFORTRAIN :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `data` parameter to `$.ajax` is not escaped properly.  The heart of your problem probably lies there:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/ajax-status-update/"+ input.attr('name') +"/",
    data: "order=" + input.attr('value'),
    type: "POST",
    complete: function(xhr_obj, msg){
        if (msg == 'success') {
            input.css("border", "1px solid green");
        } else {
            input.css("border", "1px solid red");
        }
    },
});
```

If you want to continue to use the CSRF middleware, you should probably serialize a form instead:

```
data: $('#theForm').serialize(),
```